# Activate/deactivate measuring tool OpenLayers JS

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am building an online portal and I have implemented the OpenLayers measure tool (source: https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/measure.html). I don't have a programming background and I am struggling a bit to built in an option to activate/deactivate the measuring tool through an extra form option 'None' or a deactivate button. See code below. Is there an easy way to deactivate the measure tool by default and activate it when choosing the area/length form option and deactivated again by choosing 'None' from the form list?

```
  var formatLength = function(line) {
    var length = ol.Sphere.getLength(line);
    var output;
    if (length > 100) {
      output = (Math.round(length / 1000 * 100) / 100) +
          ' ' + 'km';
    } else {
      output = (Math.round(length * 100) / 100) +
          ' ' + 'm';
    }
    return output;
  };

  var formatArea = function(polygon) {
    var area = ol.Sphere.getArea(polygon);
    var output;
    if (area > 10000) {
      output = (Math.round(area / 1000000 * 100) / 100) +
          ' ' + 'km<sup>2</sup>';
    } else {
      output = (Math.round(area * 100) / 100) +
          ' ' + 'm<sup>2</sup>';
    }
    return output;
  };

  function addInteraction() {
    var type = (typeSelect.value == 'area' ? 'Polygon' : 'LineString');
    draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
      source: source,
      type: type,
      style: styling,
      })
    });
    map.addInteraction(draw);

    var listener;
    draw.on('drawstart',
        function(evt) {
          // set sketch
          sketch = evt.feature;

          /** @type {ol.Coordinate|undefined} */
          var tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;

          listener = sketch.getGeometry().on('change', function(evt) {
            var geom = evt.target;
            var output;
            if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
              output = formatArea(geom);
              tooltipCoord = geom.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
            } else if (geom instanceof ol.geom.LineString) {
              output = formatLength(geom);
              tooltipCoord = geom.getLastCoordinate();
            }
            measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
            measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
          });
        }, this);

    draw.on('drawend',
        function() {
          measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-static';
          measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
          // unset sketch
          sketch = null;
          // unset tooltip so that a new one can be created
          measureTooltipElement = null;
          createMeasureTooltip();
          ol.Observable.unByKey(listener);
        }, this);
  }

 /**
   * Let user change the geometry type.
   */
  typeSelect.onchange = function() {
    map.removeInteraction(draw);
    addInteraction();
  };

  addInteraction();
```

Comment: That would be much easier using the vector styles method used in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure-style.html
 If you are using OpenLayers 4 a few changes are needed. Displacement for regular shapes is not supported on OL4 but you can use the regular shape image as an icon and set an anchor instead, there is a bug when cloning text styles and the overlay layers used by interactions cannot be accessed but workarounds are possible https://codepen.io/mike-000/pen/mdwwzmV

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and clarification in codepen!